# Circular LinkedList implementation in Java

Tags: java, linked-list, circular-list

This is an assignment. I have to create a circular linked list and remove every third number in the list. When my program reaches the end of the list it should go back to the head and continue the process until only one number remains.

I've searched online and some other reference books but couldn't solve my problem. Most of the references that I've found say things such as:

> Beside the fact that circular lists have no end, they are quite the same as regular lists

or (taken from my textbook):

> A singly-linked list is circularly linked if the successor of the last node is the first

But these don't tell how to do it. I've also tried using some code I found on this site, but that did not clear anything up.

I can get as far as creating a list (I don't know if it's a circular linked list) and displaying it, but the order of the elements is strange:

- if the list has 6 numbers, the list will be 1,6,5,4,3,2.
- if the list has 8 numbers, the list will be 1,8,7,6,5,4,3,2.

Without getting a correct list, I can do the deletion properly. What is wrong with the following code:

```
public class LastNumberDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LastNumberNode ll=new LastNumberNode();
        System.out.println("how long is the list: ");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = keyboard.nextInt();

        if(input<=0) {
            System.out.println("no number to creat list");
        }
        if(input==1) {
            System.out.println("The Last number is 1.");
        }
        else {
            String[] n=new String[input];
            for(int index=0; index<n.length; index++)
                n[index]=Integer.toString(index+1);
            for(String e:n)
                ll.add(e);
            System.out.print("The list contains: \n");
            ll.print();
            System.out.print("\nThe last number is: ");
            ll.remove();
            ll.print();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
//The circular linked list class
class LastNumberNode{
    private class Node{
        String value;  
        Node next;     

        Node(String val, Node n){
            value = val;
            next = n;
        }

        Node(String val){
            value=val;
            next=null;
        }
    } //This brace was missing - Edd

    private Node first;

    public LastNumberNode(){
      first = null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){        
       return first == null;
    }

    public int size(){
        int count = 0;
        Node p = first.next;   
        while (p != first){
            count ++;
            p = p.next;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public void add(String e) {
        Node p=new Node(e);
        if(first==null){
            first=p;
            first.next=first;
        }
        else{
            first.next=new Node(e,first.next);
        }
    }

    public void remove(){
        while(size()>0){
            Node target=first.next.next;   
            Node temp=first;               
            target=target.next;          
            last.next=temp;
            first=target;
        }
    }

    public void print(){
        Node ref=first;
        for(int index=-1; index<size();index++)
            System.out.print(ref.value+" ");
        ref=ref.next;
    }
} //Extra brace removed - Edd
```

Comment: The brace closing the inner class `Node` was placed right at the very bottom of the `LastNumberNode` class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you add a new `Node` to your list, you add the new `Node` into the second position (`first.next` points to your newly added node), but this newly added node has `first` as its next node, leaving the rest of the list unreferenced (And thus garbage-collected and destroyed). With your `add` method as it is, it's impossible for your list to contain anything other than 0, 1 or 2 `Node`s. It's a bit odd to add new `Node` into the middle of the list; either add it to the front (`newnode.next = first; first = newnode; last.next = first;`), or keep a reference to the back of the list (as others have suggested), and add it there.

Personally, I'd restructure the `LastNumberNode` class so that it has the following methods for manipulating the linkedlist:

- `private void addNode(Node node)`
- `private void removeNode(Node node)`
- `private Node findNode(Node nextNode)`

If you maintain a reference to the last node in the list then your `addNode(Node node)` method can be something like the following:

```
if(isEmpty()) {
    first = node;
    last = node;
}
else {
    Node tail = last;
    tail.next = node;
    node.next = first;
    last = node;
}
```

`removeNode(Node node)` is based around the following:

```
Node prevNode = findNode(node);

if(node == first) {
    first = node.next;
    last.next = first;
}
else if(node == last) {
    prevNode.next = first;
    last = prevNode;
}
else {
    prevNode.next = node.next;
}
```

If I were to implement of this I'd probably do the reduction of the list down to a single `Node` using this sort of approach:

```
public String reduceList() {
    Node curNode = first;
    while(first != last) {
        removeNode(curNode.getNext().getNext());
        curNode = curNode.getNext().getNext();
    }

    return first.getValue();
}
```

As a final point, I wouldn't bother filling an array with sequential numbers and then walking it to add the elements to your list. I'd just go straight for something like the following:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= input; i++) {
    linkedlist.add(new Integer(i).toString());
}
```

Comment: Hi Edd, thank you very much for your suggestions. I rework those methods. now my code for the remove()is: Node target=first.next; target.next=target.next.next;
first=target.next; It works perfectly. Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

Your `add` method inserts the elements directly after `first` if first is already set:

```
first.next = new Node(e, first.next);
```

This leads to the observed behaviour.

You need to keep track of the **last** element of the list and add the new element as `last.next` if you want to append the new element at the end of the list. One way to do this is to simply save a reference to the last element in a member variable of the list class, another would be to traverse the list until you find the node linking to `first` which would be the last node.

Comment: i replaced it with this: else{last.next= new Node(e, first.next);} but java showed me nullpointerexception.

Comment: Doing that links the last node to the new node, and the new node to the second node. I'm fairly sure that's not what you wanted to do.

Comment: thanks guys. that's what i did. i've changed that bit to: last.next=new Node(e) and then last = last.next, and then last.next = first. it works. now the problem is to delete very third item from the list.