# Creating an array that works like a torus

Tags: java, arrays

I have create a program that takes a random array which is created by starting from 0 and adding Math.random() (double between 0 and 0.999) n times, and calculates the weighted average of each position within a certain radius. I currently have a program that does this but i was wondering how to create one using a torus. The basic principle is the last element is now equal to the first element and when the first element updates its position it takes into account the difference between the other elements including some of the last elements in the array.

Any help on the matter would be much appreciated. Its not help with the coding but with the principle behind it, I cant work out how this would be possible for multiple iterations.

heres the code so far that works for one iteration. After one the code is incorrect and calculates the wrong values.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
* Created by jameshales on 12/03/2014.
 */
public class Torus {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###"); //  this sets all decimals to a max of 3 decimal places.


    System.out.println("how many numbers of agents on the real line?"); // This asks the question "how many numbers on the real line?" to the user.

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = 0;
    n=Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine()); // the scanner reads the input and assigns it to the variable n


    double[] agentPosition = new  double[n];  // create an array with decimal places allowed called agentPosition
    double[] newAgentPosition = new double[n];  // create an array with decimal places allowed called newAgentPosition
    double[] originalAgentPosition = new double[n];  // create an array with decimal places allowed called originalAgentPosition

    System.out.println("Please select your desired radius? select 1 normally"); // This asks the question "Please select your desired radius?


    double r = 0;
    r = input.nextDouble(); // the scanner reads the next input and assigns it to the variable r

    int t = 0;  // sets t to 0

    double epsilon = 0.001;  // this allows us to sets epsilon to 0.


    // start the array from position 0 with its value set to 0

    for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) {   // starting from position 1 it creates a random number between 0 and 0.999 and adds it to the previous agentPosition to fill the array in a random increasing way.

        if (i > 0)
            agentPosition[i] = agentPosition[i - 1] + Math.random(); // this equation creates the random array 
        else agentPosition[i] =0.0;
    }

    System.arraycopy(agentPosition,0,originalAgentPosition,0,n);
    // This takes the first randomly created array(agentPosition), copyies each element starting from 0 to n and calls it originalAgentPosition.



    while(true) { // This is the start of the while loop, this will keep running until false


        for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) {

            // this will go through the array 1 position at a time in an increasing order from position 0 to n-1

            double total1 = agentPosition[i];    // sets the initial value of total1 to 0

            double total2 = 0;    // sets the initial value of total2 to 0

            int numposition = 1;  // this starts at 1 so it includes the position in the array when dividing.(also stops dividing by 1)


                for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {   // this will work from the initial value of the array to the one before the one selected.

                    if ((agentPosition[i] - agentPosition[j]) <= r) {  // this calculates the absolute value of the difference between 2 positions on the array. (from i working downwards)


                        numposition++;         // this sums the number of positions within the radius of the chosen position.

                        total1 += agentPosition[j];   // this sums up all the values within the radius below to the total1.
                    } else break;  // stops the program once it has passed a position of a distance of 1

                }

                for (int k = i + 1; k <= n - 1 ; k++) { // this will go from the one after the position selected to the last position in the array to test if the distance is greater than 1, stops otherwise..

                    if (Math.abs(agentPosition[k] - agentPosition[i]) <= r) {     // this calculates the absolute value of the difference between 2 positions on the array(i and positions greater).


                        numposition++;      // this sums the number of positions within the radius of the chosen position.

                        total2 += agentPosition[k]; // this sums up all the values within the radius above to the total1.
                    } else break;    // stops the program once it has passed a position of a distance of 1
                }


                for (int j = n - 2; j >= 1; j--) {   // this will work from the initial value of the array to the one before the one selected.

                    if (((agentPosition[n-1] + agentPosition[i]) - agentPosition[j]) <= r) {  // this calculates the absolute value of the difference between 2 positions on the array. (from i working downwards)

                        numposition++;

                        total1 += (agentPosition[j] - agentPosition[n - 1]);   // this sums up all the values within the radius below to the total1.
                    }    else break;// stops the program once it has passed a position of a distance of 1

                }


                for (int k = 1; k <= n - 2 ; k++) { // this will go from the one after the position selected to the last position in the array to test if the distance is greater than 1, stops otherwise..

                    if (Math.abs((agentPosition[i] - agentPosition[n - 1]) - agentPosition[k]) <= r) {     // this calculates the absolute value of the difference between 2 positions on the array(i and positions greater).


                        numposition++;      // this sums the number of positions within the radius of the chosen position.


                        total2 += (agentPosition[n - 1] + agentPosition[k]); // this sums up all the values within the radius above to the total1.
                    }     else break;// stops the program once it has passed a position of a distance of 1
                }


                newAgentPosition[i] = (total1 + total2) / numposition; // this calculates the new weighted average. ( sum of assigned random variable/ sum of position)

            }

        for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++){

            if (newAgentPosition[i] > originalAgentPosition[n - 1]){
                newAgentPosition[i] = newAgentPosition[i] - originalAgentPosition[n - 1];
            }

            if(newAgentPosition[i] < 0) {  // This checks if the agentPosition is smaller than 0 and then adds the largest agent to make all the elements within the range.
                newAgentPosition[i] = newAgentPosition[i] + originalAgentPosition[n - 1];
            }

        }

        t++;  // This sums up how many iterations it will take.

        double largestDiff = 0.0;  // This assigns largestDiff to 0

        for (int i = 0; i <= n-1; i++) {

            double diff = Math.abs(agentPosition[i] - newAgentPosition[i]);  // This calculates the difference between the previous and current array at position i.

            if(diff > largestDiff)  // If the difference between the agents is bigger than 0, assign it to the variable largestDiff.
                largestDiff = diff;

        }

        if(largestDiff <= epsilon){  // This checks if the difference is bigger than the set epsilon,

            break;  // This stops the program if the difference is smaller than epsilon
        }

        agentPosition = new double[n];

        System.arraycopy(newAgentPosition, 0, agentPosition, 0, n);  // This takes the newly generated array(newAgentPosition), copyies each element starting from 0 to n and assigns it back to agentPosition. (this stops the problem j and with taking the newly created elements.)

    }


    for (int i = 0 ; i <= n - 1; i++) {   // starting from position 1 it creates a random number between 0 and 0.999 and adds it to the previous agentPosition to fill the array in a random increasing way.

        System.out.println(i + ": " + df.format(originalAgentPosition[i]) + "\t->\t" + df.format(agentPosition[i]));

    }

    int sumdofclusters = 1;  // This sets the sum of clusters to 1

    System.out.println("The different clusters are:\n" + df.format(agentPosition[0]));   // This prints out the first cluster only.

    for (int i = 1; i <= n - 1 ; i++) {

        if(Math.abs(agentPosition[i] - agentPosition[i - 1]) >= epsilon) {  // This checks if the element after the element at hand is different by a set epsilon.(how to work out different clusters)

            sumdofclusters++;  // This sums the number of clusters.


            System.out.println(df.format(agentPosition[i])); // This prints out the different clusters other than the first 1.
        }

    }
    System.out.println("Number of clusters is:" + sumdofclusters); // This prints out the number of clusters.

    System.out.println("Number of iterations:" + t);   // This prints out the number of iterations.


}
}
```

Comment: You are looking for a circular list. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338868/circular-linkedlist-implementation-in-java

Comment: Yeah circular list, a torus would be circular list of circular lists, which would be an interesting concept. :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice i will start researching circular lists. Don't think this is going to be as easy as i first thought. :s

Comment: A circular list is quite easy with modulus division, as described below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a circular list using an array with modulus division.

```
getElementAt(double[] arr, int index)
{
    index = index % arr.length;
    index = index + arr.length; // If index is negative, modulus division gives us negative result, so this makes it positive.
    index = index % arr.length; // In case the previous step made index >= n
    return arr[index]
}
```

If `n` is `arr.length` then

`0 <= index < n` will be like normal.

`n <= index` will wrap around the list (e.g. `arr[n] == arr[0]`, `arr[n+1] == arr[1]`, etc.)

`index < 0` will wrap around the list in the other direction (e.g. `arr[-1] == arr[n-1]`, `arr[-2] == arr[n-2]`, etc.)

Comment: Just for clarity (and to facilitate debugging) I'd recommend breaking that into 2-3 separate statements, vs one long line.